How can I use Axios with Server-sent events (SSE) in the browser?
I'm trying to receive Server-sent events (SSE) in the browser. My application uses axios (v1.6.8) to make API calls. This code (courtesy of this answer) works in node:
const getStreamAxios = () => {
  axios.get('https://my-domain.com/api/getStream', {
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/event-stream',
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('axios got a response');
      const stream = response.data;

      stream.on('data', data => {
          console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
      });
      
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error('got an error', e);
    });    
}

But in the browser, the Promise is never fulfilled (i.e.: I don't get the console message "axios got a response"). Instead I get this warning in the console:

The provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.

The issue is not in the API endpoint; in addition to checking it with node, I have verified it also works with Apidog and EventSource in the browser.

The root of the problem is, axios as of v1.6.8, uses XMLHttpRequest in the browser (see axios docs). This means you can only use responseType: 'stream' in node.
This was finally addressed in v1.7.0, which allows you to use fetch instead of XHR, like so:
const getStreamAxios = () => {
  axios.get('https://my-domain.com/api/getStream', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/event-stream',
    },
    responseType: 'stream',
    adapter: 'fetch', // <- this option can also be set in axios.create()
  })
    .then(async (response) => {
      console.log('axios got a response');
      const stream = response.data;      

      // consume response
      const reader = stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();
      while (true) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        console.log(value);
      }
    })
    // catch/etc.
}

If you are really invested in an older version of axios, there is a dodgy-looking workaround, using the onDownloadProgress option:
const getStreamAxios = () => {
  axios.get('https://my-domain.com/api/getStream', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/event-stream',
    },
    onDownloadProgress: (evt) => {
      // Parse response from evt.event.target.responseText || evt.event.target.response
      // The target holds the accumulator + the current response, so basically everything from the beginning on each response
      // Note that it's evt.target instead of evt.event.target for older axios versions
      let data = evt.event.target.responseText;
      console.log(data);
    }
  })

Caveat
Note that, regardless of the option you choose, you will still have to write something to consume the server-sent events. Here's an example using @server-sent-stream/web:
const getStreamAxios = () => {
  // axios.get(...) etc.
  .then(async (response) => {
    console.log('axios got a response');
    const stream = response.data; // <- should be a ReadableStream

    const decoder = new EventSourceStream();
    stream.pipeThrough(decoder);

    // Read from the EventSourceStream
    const reader = decoder.readable.getReader();

    while (true) {
      const { value, done } = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;

      // The value will be a `MessageEvent`.
      // MessageEvent {data: 'message data', lastEventId: '', …}
      console.log(value)
    }
  })
}

If you don't want to parse this yourself, you can look at the native EventSource API. If you need more options not provided by EventSource (such as setting additional headers), you  can take a look at options like sse.js, or this extended EventSource implementation

Using TextDecoderStream() is not reliable. You might end up with multiple events in a single string!

I tried axios, but solved the problem with fetch instead of axios.
You may have a look at my code, it works for SSE in NextJS.
Also this video enlightened me:
Build a Web App with Response Streaming | LangChain JS Tutorial #3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUeTSfjNFS0
What's more:
1.I found EventSource for SSE doesn't really work in Nextjs.
2.For server side streaming, I used this:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#streaming
I struggled to solve this problem for literally 3 days,
hope my solution could bring you a little bit of help.
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const page = () => {
  const [streamData, setStreamData] = useState("init");

  async function readData() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/nextstream", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "text/event-stream",
      },
    });
    let initStr=""
    for await (const chunk of res.body) {
      let decChunk = new TextDecoder().decode(chunk);
      console.log(decChunk);
      initStr+=decChunk
      setStreamData(streamData + initStr);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{streamData}</div>;

};

export default page;

